# php best way to redirect according to visitor's language

Tags: php, redirect, region

I want to identify the visitor's region. My website has 4 language versions and I want to detect whether a visitor is visiting my site from English speaking country or russian, or arabic or spanish speaking country. What is the best way to do it?

Comment: use $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; and on the basis of IP list do the following to your visitors

Comment: I hate websites that do that. Give the user the choice to select whichever language he wants.

Comment: You should use `HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE` and also offer the choice of setting language manually. GEOIP doesn't always work as people visit through proxies/VPNs/corporate gateways which don't reflect what language they actually speak let alone telling you where they are located!

Answer (score 1):

This is what we use in our scripts to do similar detection:

```
function get_preferred_lang() {
    if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"])) {
        preg_match_all('#([a-z-]+) *(?:; *q=([0-9.]+))?#', strtolower($_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"]), $matches);
        $accept = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);
        foreach ($accept as $key => $val)
        $accept[$key] = $val == '' ? 1.0 : (float) $val;
        arsort($accept);
        return substr(array_shift(array_keys($accept)),0,2); 
      } else {
        return 'unknown';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Use MaxMind API for PHP:

[INSTRUCTIONS](http://www.finalwebsites.com/forums/topic/how-to-use-maxmind-geoip-for-websites)

[DOWNLOADS](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/downloadable)

Answer (score -1):

You can use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];` to fetch user IP address and on the basis of this use this link to proceed further according to your requirement [GEOIP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.geoip.php)